# How to remove row in jasper reports when no data?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a data table in using jasper reports. How can I remove a row if there is no data in that row of if any specific value is null using if statement.

Comment: Is this question, still open consider to accept an answer if useful or pass your own.

Answer (score 0):

The **best solution** is to remove it from the datasource (hence by your query).

However you can also use the `printWhenExpression` on the `detail` band

```
<detail>
    <band height="21">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{Field1}!=null && $F{Field2}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
    ...your fields....
    </band> 
</detail>
```

Note: I'm using `new Boolean(expression)` so that it is compatible with jasper report 3.0 if you are using 6.0 this can be removed, and expression can be put directly.

Inside the `printWhenExpression` you can set any boolean expression using as in this example java since I have `language="java"` attribute on my jasper report tag